# Can I view the RCS log with diffs?

Tags: rcs

Sadly, there is no `RCS` tag on Unix.stackexchange or ServerFault, so I am posting this on StackOverflow.

I'm spoiled by SVN/Git, and I need to see the history of a file. With my scripts I am using RCS to track changes made to system configuration files, so it would be neat if I could view them like I do with Git. for git I use `git log -p` to get this kind of output.

Is there a flag for `rlog` or `rcsdiff` or anything that lets me get a log that has the diffs?

Or must I use `rcsdiff` and a shell script to implement this myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`rcshist`](http://invisible-island.net/rcshist/rcshist.html)  (written by Ian Dowse) does what was requested.  I do not know of prebuilt packages, but it builds easily.

Here is [sample output](http://invisible-island.net/rcshist/rcshist.html#usage):

```
REV:1.346               aclocal.m4          2012/09/03 17:21:43       tom
tags:            xterm-281s, xterm-281r, xterm-281q, xterm-281p, xterm-281o,
                 xterm-281n, xterm-281m, xterm-281l, xterm-281k, xterm-281j,
                 xterm-281i, xterm-281h, xterm-281g, xterm-281f, xterm-281e

   change default for --with-xpm

--- aclocal.m4  2012/08/25 23:05:32     1.345
+++ aclocal.m4  2012/09/03 17:21:43     1.346
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-dnl $XTermId: rcshist.html,v 1.16 2015/03/01 20:34:33 tom Exp $
+dnl $XTermId: rcshist.html,v 1.16 2015/03/01 20:34:33 tom Exp $
 dnl
 dnl ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 dnl
@@ -3554,7 +3554,7 @@
 AC_SUBST(no_pixmapdir)
 ])dnl
 dnl ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-dnl CF_WITH_XPM version: 1 updated: 2012/07/22 09:18:02
+dnl CF_WITH_XPM version: 2 updated: 2012/09/03 05:42:04
 dnl -----------
 dnl Test for Xpm library, update compiler/loader flags if it is wanted and
 dnl found.
@@ -3571,7 +3571,7 @@
 AC_ARG_WITH(xpm,
 [  --with-xpm=DIR          use Xpm library for colored icon, may specify path],
        [cf_Xpm_library="$withval"],
-       [cf_Xpm_library=no])
+       [cf_Xpm_library=yes])
 AC_MSG_RESULT($cf_Xpm_library)

 if test "$cf_Xpm_library" != no ; then
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    rlog filename
```

Will show you the basic history.

```
    rcsdiff -r5.1 -r5.2 filename
```

To see a diff between two revisions.  Do not put  a space after the -r.

Comment: I am not asking how to do these things. I know how to do these things, these are the basic commands. I am saying I want to see the diffs inside the `rlog` log. Like if I have 10 revisions I want to see all 9 diffs simultaneously.

Comment: @StevenLu: I'm pretty sure `rlog` has no such feature.

Answer (score 1):

Read the ,v file. It contains the full history.